# Removing null references from a HashSet

Tags: java, null, set, hashset

Is there a simple way of removing null references from a HashSet like 
the way we can delete them from a List using `list.removeAll(Collections.singletonList(null))` ?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Since a `Set` can not contain the same value twice (including `null`, if it is supported by the specific `Set` implementation), simply doing [`set.remove(null)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) would be sufficient.

Note that you don't even need to check for the existence of `null` before, because `remove(null)` will simply do nothing if the `Set` doesn't contain `null`.

Comment: Is there a .NET alternative to a `HashSet<string>` that does not allow null values?

Answer (score 4):

A `HashSet`, being a set, only contains one "copy" of any object, which also means that it can only contain one instance of `null`. Thus, you can just use `HashSet.remove(null)`.